# facebook-php-sdk how to upload photo to wall or album?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Hi Guys i'm e newbie in php programin and facebook app, i found this code and it works very well for TEXT posts, but my requirements are that I have to UPLOAD a picture too, i tried by addin ['source' => '$image_source'] on the arrey but does not work...
How can I upload a PHOTO ?

```
<?php
include_once("config.php");


if($_POST)
{
    //Post variables we received from user
    $userPageId     = $_POST["userpages"];
    $userMessage    = $_POST["message"];
    $image_source = "http://www.example.com/image.jpg"
    if(strlen($userMessage)<1) 
    {
        //message is empty
        $userMessage = 'No message was entered!';
    }

        //HTTP POST request to PAGE_ID/feed with the publish_stream
        $post_url = '/'.$userPageId.'/feed';

        //posts message on page statues 
        $msg_body = array(
        'message' => $userMessage,
        'source' => '$image_source'
        );

    if ($fbuser) {
      try {
            $postResult = $facebook->api($post_url, 'post', $msg_body );
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
      }
    }else{
     $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=>$homeurl,'scope'=>$fbPermissions));
     header('Location: ' . $loginUrl);
    }

    //Show sucess message
    if($postResult)
     {
         echo '<html><head><title>Message Posted</title><link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /></head><body>';
         echo '<div id="fbpageform" class="pageform" align="center">';
         echo '<h1>Your message is posted on your facebook wall.</h1>';
         echo '<a class="button" href="'.$homeurl.'">Back to Main Page</a> <a target="_blank" class="button" href="http://www.facebook.com/'.$userPageId.'">Visit Your Page</a>';
         echo '</div>';
         echo '</body></html>';
     }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use the `feed` endpoint to post photos. You should be using `/me/photos` with the `publish_stream` permission. To post to an album you need the `/ALBUM_ID/photos` endpoint

```
   $msg_body = array(
    'message' => $userMessage,
    'source' => '@'.'$image_source'
   );

   $postResult = $facebook->api('/me/photos/','post', $msg_body);
```

For using urls not associated with your site you need to use `url`

```
  $msg_body = array(
    'message' => $userMessage,
    'url' => 'http://somepage.com/img.png'
   );
```

Comment: Thank you for you replay but i'm getting thiss message 
Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 26: failed creating formpost data thrown in /homez.666/makestre/www/autopost/inc/base_facebook.php on line 972

Comment: @user1898399 in the most up to date PHP SDK line 972 is a bracket... https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php#L972 so I am not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: I changed the library and still i do have that message but in line 977 and it is this code:

    if ($result === false) {
     LINE977-> $e = new FacebookApiException(array(
        'error_code' => curl_errno($ch),
        'error' => array(
        'message' => curl_error($ch),
        'type' => 'CurlException',
        ),
      ));
      curl_close($ch);
      throw $e;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
  }

Comment: @user1898399 try fixing the `source` parameter, it may not be getting the file correctly.

Comment: What source ?

ps.with this script and library i'm posting TEXT alredy it work's just fine I have all the permittions...

Comment: this is my source: $image_source = 'http://makestream.com/www/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/logo1.png';

Comment: @user1898399 **Re-read the answer**, you are using the wrong endpoint/api call, so whatever you did earlier will not work for photos. Also you did not state that the url was not from your site.

Comment: 1. I dont know exatcly what do I have to do with that api call since i did not write this code i found it somewhere, 2. the image is from the  same website where the app si working, 3. can you pls tell my what to do this is my second day without any result...

Comment: @user1898399 the above answer (second block of code) works with the latest official PHP SDK, I cannot help you with modified versions of the SDK for I do know what code is in it, I will be guessing in the dark. Debugging some code you found online in the comments is not productive at all. I suggest you find out from the author of the code you took *somewhere*.